# Center content that is inside of an iFrame with PHP $_get

Tags: php, iframe, get, center

*Does anyone know how to center the content that is inside of an iFrame? I was thinking doing something with Javascript and innerHTML but I can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated :) Even setting the width of the iFrame to match the width of the content (maybe like a jpg url or something) would be great because then I can just center the iFrame on my page when it's the proper width of the page it's displaying.*

---

Edit: I figured out how to get that part to work (with code I found on google) but the problem is when I try to do it in PHP (using _get) it stops working... for example make a php file called test.php

Here is the code for the php document:

```
<?php
print '<title>blah blah blah</title><body bgcolor="#505050"><br />
<script type="text/javascript">document.domain="' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["image"]) .  '";</script> <SCRIPT LANGUAGE=\'javascript\'> 
function resize_iframe(){ 
document.getElementById(\'textoforo\').height=100; 
document.getElementById(\'textoforo\').height=window.frames["textoforo"].document.body.scrollHeight; 
document.getElementById(\'textoforo\').width=100; 
document.getElementById(\'textoforo\').width=window.frames["textoforo"].document.body.scrollWidth; 
}
</SCRIPT><div style="z-index:99; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; background-color:#505050;"><table style="vertical-align:middle; text-align:center; height:90%; width:100%; background-color:#FFF"><center><td style="vertical-align:middle; height:100%;"><center><iframe id=\'textoforo\' 
name=\'textoforo\' 
border=1 
src=\'' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["image"]) . '\' 
width=768 
height=800 
MARGINWIDTH=0 
MARGINHEIGHT=0 
onload=\'resize_iframe();\' 
> 
</iframe></center></td></center></table></center></div></body>';
?>
```

and go to the url:

"//test.php?image=http://www.all2need.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/African-Daisy-Flower.jpg"

When you load the page it doesn't work, but if you copy the source code and past it into an html document it does work!!!!! ???? So I think the javascript is trying to retrieve the height and width variables before PHP has inputed the image URL (using _Get) so it returns nil values? I don't know... any thoughts?

Comment: I know I could just use <img> tags for an image but the iFrame will be for a few other things as well like html pages that contain a collage of <img> tags and I want to show all the images at once so I just iFrame the page.

Comment: There is probably a better way to go about this with simple javascript time delays or something, I know nothing of javascript though... like I said this [javascript] code was borrowed from another coding forum :)

Comment: "document.getElementById" is the problem, for whatever reason javascript doesn't read it if it's echoed from PHP /: How can I check if it's loaded in PHP and then resize it rather than doing it in Javascript? Is that even possible since PHP is server side?

Answer (score 2):

You'r looking for a `DOM-Ready` method. You could write one yourself, but if you don't have a lot of experience with javascript you might want to consider using a Javascript-framework that handles that for you.

These should help you determine, when to start you resize/repositioning script.

- http://api.jquery.com/ready/
- http://mootools.net/docs/core/Utilities/DOMReady

  **jQuery** Example:

  ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
     /* Your logic here */
   });
  ```

  Which is equivalent to calling:

  ```
   $(function() {
     /* Your logic here */
   });
  ```

  **MooTools** Example:

  ```
  window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    /* Your logic here */
  });
  ```

On a personal note: the jQuery society is a bit bigger and better supported, so you might want to use something which is more commonly used.

Answer (score 1):

The content of an iframe is just a seperate html-document. You could use a php-file, but there is no need to put everything between the php-tags and print (use 'echo') all the html-code. Make it a proper page with `<head>, <html> and <body>` tags.
You can then load an external css-file if you want to style the content of the iframe.

The iframe itself is part of the main html-page it is placed in. Javascript you execute in the iframe will only affect elements inside that iframe. To work around that, you could place the javascript in the main page and adress it from within the iframe with

```
parent.yourfunction();
```

And if you only want to place an image on you page, why use an iframe? Use a `<div>` with an image inside and style it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with loading an image straight into an `iframe` is that it has no style or any proper position in the HTML `DOM` that it can be manipulated. It will just show the image as it is. So the solution would be to resize the iframe to the contents size (different for each browser) and then center the iframe.

I don't see, where PHP fits in all of this.

Perhaps this is an nice alternative: http://fancybox.net/ (check the example's on the bottom)

Comment: The HTML code that I used in the PHP that is being printed works, it properly sized the image with no problem because it gets the content size.... When I run that HTML code through PHP though and enter the image URL in the php's _get variables the code stops working because the javascript updates too soon... (I'm assuming that's the problem) so this is what I'm looking to solve.

Comment: So the PHP-script, which is still rendering the image is still loading? And you want to activate the javascript when that moment is done?

Comment: Yes :) If that is the problem, I'm only assuming that's the problem!

Comment: Nevermind, the problem is when PHP echoes "document.getElementById" to javascript, javascrip ignores it for some reason.. that's why my code in HTML works but the SAME EXACT code in PHP doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You should figure out whether the target url is an image or not.
If it is an image use this way to set the Dimensions of the Iframe:

```
list ($width, $height) = getimagesize(htmlspecialchars($_GET["image"]));
```

Then you can set the width and height directly to the Iframe.

If its not an image use this way:

```
    <?php
print '<title>blah blah blah</title><body bgcolor="#505050">
<script type="text/javascript">
function getDocHeight() {
    var D = document.getElementById("textoforo").document;
    return Math.max(
        Math.max(D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight)
    );
}
function getDocWidth() {
    var D = document.getElementById("textoforo").document;
    return Math.max(
        Math.max(D.body.scrollWidth, D.documentElement.scrollWidth),
        Math.max(D.body.offsetWidth, D.documentElement.offsetWidth),
        Math.max(D.body.clientWidth, D.documentElement.clientWidth)
    );
}
function resize_iframe()
{ 
    /*
    Use getDocHeight and getDocWidth to set the dimensions
    */
}
</SCRIPT>
<style type="text/css">
html,body
{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
</style>
<div style="z-index:99; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; background-color:#FF00FF;">
<iframe id="textoforo" 
name="textoforo" 
border="1" 
src="' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["image"]) . '"
MARGINWIDTH="0" 
MARGINHEIGHT="0" 
onload="resize_iframe();"> 
</iframe>
</div>
</body>';
?>
```

Nevertheless, I still have problems understanding your question and the use of it.

Edit: The Onload Event is working correct for me (FF, IE). Which Browser do you use?

Comment: Safari, it works fine for me too but when I put it in PHP and echo it all of a sudden it stops working ??

Comment: I used your php code above in Safari and FireFox and both times the iFrame had the same dimensions, it never adjusted it's width and height to fit the content /: